How to calculate conditional power for data that is NOT normally distributed?
Study information:
Two pararell arms, active group and Placebo group. The planned sample size is 168 = 84*2. Since our primary endpoint is not normally distributed (known from other previous similar studies.), the primary analysis specified is Wilcoxon rank sum test. There is a planed interim analysis (IA), occuring at ~50% subjects complete DB period. The conditional power is planned to be calculated. The formula specified in the statistical analysis plan is as follows.
normal CDF [ Zn/sqrt(t(1-t)) - Zα/2/sqrt(1-t)].
CDF = Cumulative Distribution Function.
Zn is the z statistics from Wilcoxon rank-sum test for the comparison between active vs Placebo.
t is the information factor, which is the actual number of the subjects in the study at the time of interim analysis divided by the planned number of subjects for the study (168 = 84*2), i.e., n/168.
Now it was decided the IA will be performed a little early. That is, totally there will be 78 or 80 subjects. Each arm will be 39 or 40.
I already searched online, read papers, and used ChatGPT, but I still have questions that would like to get help from Experts here.
1.  If plugging in the 'z' from the Wilcoxon rank sum test as Zn into the above formlua, as planned, to calculate the conditional power, will it be a valid approach with our sample size at the IA?

Will this formula be appropriate for our data, espeically with such sample size? If not, are there some other formula?

My current idea is, since my sample size is not large enough, I should do simulation, at least as a back-up for the planned 'plug z in' approach.  See how much differences there will be. But I am not sure how to do that.  Can anyone please help me on that?



Try using latex math in your question. Also, you don't have to sign your name!

Out of curiosity, how does "conditional power" differ from "power"?  Another question: usually the p-value of the Wilcoxon test is computed with a Normal approximation when sample sizes are sufficiently large (which they are here).  Doesn't that settle the issue of whether the formula you quote is applicable?
